# Facing some errors in react CRUD operation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern

In my code I am doing **CRUD** operation the problem is that when I am updating any single data it works perfectly but after that when I click on edit button for update the 2nd data and did not change anything then it will save previous data on it means the data which I edit on first data also save to 2nd data.
**Here is my code**

```
import {
  Button,
  Card,
  Col,
  FormControl,
  InputGroup,
  Modal,
  Row,
  Table,
} from "@themesberg/react-bootstrap";
import TableRow from "../../../components/Tables";
import BootstrapTables from "../../tables/BootstrapTables";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import axios from "axios";

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

const Bpm = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState([]);
  const [updateProductType, setupdateProductType] = useState("");

  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [addProduct, setaddProduct] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);


  const fetchData = async () => {
    await axios
      .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/attributes/3`)
      .then((response) => {
        setValue(response.data);
      });
  };


 

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

 

  const [updateshow, updatesetShow] = useState(false);
  const [updateid, setupdateid] = useState({});

  const updatehandleClose = () => updatesetShow(false);
  const updatehandleShow = (_id, att_value) => {
    updatesetShow(true);
    setupdateid({ id: _id, att_value: att_value });
  };

  const handleUpdate = async () => {
    console.log(updateid, updateProductType, "update walli id");

    await axios
      .patch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/attributes/`, {
        _id: updateid.id,
        att_type: 3,
        att_value: updateProductType,
      })
      .then((res) => console.log("updated"));
    fetchData();
    updatehandleClose();
  };

  

  const attributeName = "BPM";

  return (
    <>
  

      <Card border="light" className="shadow-sm mb-4">
        <Card.Body className="pb-0">
          <Table
            responsive
            className="table-centered table-nowrap rounded mb-0"
          >
            <thead className="thead-light">
              <tr>
                <th className="border-0">#</th>
                <th className="border-0">BPM</th>
                <th className="border-0"></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {value.map((pt, index) => {
                const { att_value, _id } = pt;
                return (
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <Card.Link href="#" className="text-primary fw-bold">
                        {index + 1}
                      </Card.Link>
                    </td>
                    <td className="fw-bold">
                      <FontAwesomeIcon
                      // icon={sourceIcon}
                      // className={`icon icon-xs text-${sourceIconColor} w-30`}
                      />
                      {att_value}
                    </td>

                    <Modal show={updateshow} onHide={updatehandleClose}>
                      <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title>{`Edit ${attributeName}`}</Modal.Title>
                      </Modal.Header>
                      <form onSubmit={() => handleUpdate()}>
                        <Modal.Body>
                          <InputGroup>
                            <FormControl
                              // placeholder={updateid.att_value}
                              defaultValue={updateid.att_value}
                              aria-label="Username"
                              aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
                              onChange={(e) =>
                                setupdateProductType(e.target.value)
                              }
                            />
                          </InputGroup>
                        </Modal.Body>
                        <Modal.Footer>
                          <Button
                            variant="secondary"
                            onClick={updatehandleClose}
                          >
                            Close
                          </Button>
                          <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                            Save Changes
                          </Button>
                        </Modal.Footer>
                      </form>
                    </Modal>

                    <td style={{ width: "380px" }}>
                      <Row className="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <Col xs={12} xl={2} className="px-0">
                          <small className="fw-bold">
                            <Button
                              onClick={() => updatehandleShow(_id, att_value)}
                            >
                              Edit
                            </Button>
                          </small>
                        </Col>
                  
                      </Row>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                );
              })}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
};

export default Bpm;
```

Answer (score 0):

`updateid` and `updateProductType` inside of `const handleUpdate = async () => { ... }` are the values at the time when the function `handleUpdate()` was *created*, not when it is called.

A solution would be to pass the current values as parameters:

```
<form onSubmit={ () => handleUpdate( updateid, updateProductType ) }>
```